# I am trying to create a scrolling function and I was hoping someone could give some advice on a certain problem I am having

Tags: c++

I am working on a text editor project for the 3ds and I am working on adding a scrolling function I have found a way for the text to scroll up by doing this

```c++
if (kHeld & KEY_UP)
{
   cout << endl;
}
```

but for a basic implementation of the text scrolling down I need to insert a white space at the top of the imputed text I have tried using the insert() function but it needs to output the text again to show the inserted whitespace this is a large problem I have been stuck on for days and any suggestions you are willing to provide would be great here is my full source code if it will help thanks

```c++
// T3XTPAD-V1.0

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <3ds.h>

using namespace std;

string Output = "";

int main()
{
    gfxInitDefault();

    PrintConsole topScreen, bottomScreen;
  consoleInit(GFX_TOP, &topScreen);
  consoleInit(GFX_BOTTOM, &bottomScreen);

  consoleSelect(&bottomScreen);

    cout << endl;
    cout << "T3XTPAD-V1.0" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "[A] Edit:" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "[B] Save:" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "[Y] Open:" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "[UP/DOWN] Scroll:" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    consoleSelect(&topScreen);

    while (aptMainLoop())
    {
        hidScanInput();

    u32 kHeld = hidKeysHeld();
        u32 kDown = hidKeysDown();

        if (kDown & KEY_START)
        {
            break;
        }

        static SwkbdState swkbd;
        static char Edit[999999];
        static char Save[999999];
        static char Open[999999];
        SwkbdButton button = SWKBD_BUTTON_NONE;

        if (kDown & KEY_A)
        {
            swkbdInit(&swkbd, SWKBD_TYPE_NORMAL, 2, -1);
            swkbdSetHintText(&swkbd, "Edit:");
            button = swkbdInputText(&swkbd, Edit, sizeof(Edit));

            cout << Edit << endl;
        }

        if (kDown & KEY_B)
        {
            swkbdInit(&swkbd, SWKBD_TYPE_NORMAL, 2, -1);
            swkbdSetHintText(&swkbd, "Save:");
            button = swkbdInputText(&swkbd, Save, sizeof(Save));

            ofstream MyFile (Save);

            if (MyFile.is_open())
            {
                MyFile << Edit << endl;

                MyFile.close();
            }

        }

        if (kDown & KEY_Y)
        {
            swkbdInit(&swkbd, SWKBD_TYPE_NORMAL, 2, -1);
            swkbdSetHintText(&swkbd, "Open:");
            button = swkbdInputText(&swkbd, Open, sizeof(Open));

            ifstream MyFile (Open);

            if (MyFile.is_open())
            {
                while (getline (MyFile, Output))
                {
                    cout << Output << endl;
                }

                MyFile.close();
            }

        }

        if (kHeld & KEY_UP)
        {
            cout << endl;
        }

        if (kHeld & KEY_DOWN)
        {
      cout << endl;
        }

        gfxFlushBuffers();
        gfxSwapBuffers();
        gspWaitForVBlank();
    }

    gfxExit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to use some kind of console manipulation library like `ncurses`?